# Ubuntu 14 - Apache2 not running with ENVVARS

Tags: apache, ubuntu, puppet

I'm currently experimenting with Puppet and have run into an error where it's starting apache2 without the environment variables. I've been following [example 1](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/getting-started-with-puppet-code-manifests-and-modules) and it's a very simple manifest but it throws the below errors;

```
[Mon May 18 23:18:35.725947 2015] [core:warn] [pid 5312] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} is not defined
[Mon May 18 23:18:35.726451 2015] [core:warn] [pid 5312] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_PID_FILE} is not defined
[Mon May 18 23:18:35.726538 2015] [core:warn] [pid 5312] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_RUN_USER} is not defined
[Mon May 18 23:18:35.726611 2015] [core:warn] [pid 5312] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP} is not defined
[Mon May 18 23:18:35.726696 2015] [core:warn] [pid 5312] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
[Mon May 18 23:18:35.750730 2015] [core:warn] [pid 5312] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
[Mon May 18 23:18:35.751241 2015] [core:warn] [pid 5312] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
[Mon May 18 23:18:35.751331 2015] [core:warn] [pid 5312] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
AH00526: Syntax error on line 74 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:
Invalid Mutex directory in argument file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR}
```

I know the issue is around it not loading in the envvar file and this can be done if I don't run it from Puppet but i'm looking for a solution so I can use puppet to create servers. Any ideas?

My Puppet manifest is below:

```
# execute 'apt-get update'
exec { 'apt-update':                    # exec resource named 'apt-update'
  command => '/usr/bin/apt-get update'  # command this resource will run
}

# install apache2 package
package { 'apache2':
  require => Exec['apt-update'],        # require 'apt-update' before installing
  ensure => installed,
}

# ensure apache2 service is running
service { 'apache2':
  ensure => running,
}

# install mysql-server package
package { 'mysql-server':
  require => Exec['apt-update'],        # require 'apt-update' before installing
  ensure => installed,
}
# ensure mysql service is running
service { 'mysql':
  ensure => running,
}

# install php5 package
package { 'php5':
  require => Exec['apt-update'],        # require 'apt-update' before installing
  ensure => installed,
}

# ensure info.php file exists
file { '/var/www/html/info.php':
  ensure => file,
  content => '<?php  phpinfo(); ?>',    # phpinfo code
  require => Package['apache2'],        # require 'apache2' package before creating
}
```

Comment: Yes but **why** does it not work when running from Puppet? Have you tried debugging that at all? It should Just Work.

Comment: Because it's not loading the envvars file, but I'm asking why and how to resolve that